# Stripe - get a client secret when the amount is zero

Tags: reactjs, node.js, stripe-payments

I use the Payment Element to allow people to sign up for my service. I create an intent like this:

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [{ price }],
    // Tell stripe we don't have the card details yet.
    payment_behavior: "default_incomplete",
    payment_settings: { save_default_payment_method: "on_subscription" },
    expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
    coupon: coupon || undefined,
  });
```

This works great and I get a client secret to then render the payments element, however if I offer a discount code, which make the initial payment 0, this call does not give me a client secret, since there is "no invoice to pay". Is there any way to get a client secret and offer coupon codes that make the first payment 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Subscription doesn't require payment when it's created (because it's trialing or has a 100% discount) then it will have a `pending_setup_intent` (see [api ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-pending_setup_intent)). If you [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) this Setup Intent you should be able to get its `client_secret` and use it to collect and save payment details for future payments.